# Migration from Angular 8 to Angular 9 with g update @angular/cli@9 @angular/core@9 command

Tags: angular

I am trying to upgrade the version of my angular 8 project to 9. Currently my project is on the latest version of angular 8.  @angular/core": "~8.2.14", and "@angular/cli": "^8.3.29". The error messages I get are package incompatibilities. microsoft-adal-angular6 is not compatible with Angular 9 ? Thanks!

```
PS > ng update @angular/cli@9 @angular/core@9
>>
The installed Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.
Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Workspace extension with invalid name (defaultProject) found.
Using package manager: npm
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 65 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-webpack" has a missing peer dependency of "webpack" @ "^4.6.0".
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-webpack" has a missing peer dependency of "webpack-dev-server" @ "^3.1.4".
                  Package "microsoft-adal-angular6" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.13").
                  Package "microsoft-adal-angular6" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.13").
                  Package "apollo-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "zone.js" (requires "~0.8.20 || ~0.9.0", would install "0.10.3").
× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "C:\Users\Ncozzo.adm\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-6HxWPS\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Comment: Check your npm packages that they will support Angular9 and at what version. They perform angular update command with ```--force``` attribute. Once angular project is updated, then update/resolve your issues with npm packages. Happen to me when I need to replace some packages because old packages are retired and doesn't support newer version of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Install missing webpack dependencies

```
npm install --save-dev webpack@^4.6.0 webpack-dev-server@^3.1.4
```

Update microsoft-adal-angular6 to a compatible version

```
npm install microsoft-adal-angular6@<compatible-version>
```

Update zone.js for apollo-angular

```
npm install zone.js@~0.8.20
```

Run the migration command with --force option

```
ng update @angular/cli@9 @angular/core@9 --force
```

Replace  with a version of "microsoft-adal-angular6" that supports Angular 9. After these steps, thoroughly test your application to ensure it works with the updated dependencies.